# Dropdown jQuery Menu with these effects?

Tags: jquery, menu, slidedown

Ive been looking for a jQuery menu with a slide down effect like Yoothemes.

http://www.yootheme.com/demo/

Notice on the theme the submenu toggles or slides down.

I'm aware of the jQuery superfish menu which is ideal but the effects are slightly different.

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

Help appreciated.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to change the effect from fading in and out to sliding down and up?

Because they are different animations.

```
$("object").fadeIn(500);
$("object").fadeOut(500);
```

vs

```
$("object").animate({top:0}, 500);
$("object").animate({top:'-'+$(this).css(height)}, 500);
```

Comment: Yes, thanks max, i will try it out, is there an example or open source menu available with this type of demo?

Comment: similar effect with a different easing (the speed isn't linear unlike the example you linked to) but you can modify this if you like it  http://www.queness.com/post/1047/easy-to-style-jquery-drop-down-menu-tutorial